# My database disconnects after a while - JSP pages and MySQL

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception

I have a web application in Netbeans and I have created some jsp pages which they use methods (my methods) to get some data from classes, such as usernames, title etc.

Also I have stored the users in a table using MySQL. In order to get the username (after the user log in) I use a method getUsername().

In my jsp page I have this code:

`<%UserBean currentUser=(UserBean)(session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%> <h1><%= currentUser.getUsername() %> </h1>`

where the userBean is a class etc. Everything runs smoothly, BUT some times (I have noticed this happens when I don't use the application from the browser for a while (15-20 minutes? I don't know) I get an error status

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

and the log file in Tomcat prints

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/APle]
>   threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root causejava.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:96)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I go to inspect the file welcome_jsp.java in line 96 and it is the method that I get the username.

```
      out.print( currentUser.getUsername() );
```

I suppose the reason that I get the error is that the method returns Null.. But why is this happening? if I deploy the application again, everything will run normal!

Thank you!!

Comment: Due to session time-out, all objects bounded to session will be removed from session dictionary. Set session time-out and always check `null` before you perform action on object.

Comment: ok i will add  to the web.xml file this
<session-config> <session-timeout>30 </session-timeout></session-config> to observe if it still happens..

thx!

Comment: ok lets say the session expires. How can i prevent showing the user the error page and show him the page to login again? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%UserBean currentUser=(UserBean)(session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%> 
<h1><%= currentUser.getUsername() %> </h1>
```

Here you are taking 'UserBean' object from session and directly calling function.If you are not used your webapplication for a particular time your session will get expired and if you calling

```
<%UserBean currentUser=(UserBean)(session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%>
```

Here 'currentUser' will be null. So after that you trying to access 'currentUser' this will throw NullPointerException. So you shoud check null pointer for the object before getting value from it like

```
<%UserBean currentUser=(UserBean)(session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));
if(currentUser != null){
%>
<h1><%= currentUser.getUsername() %> </h1>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Thx for the response! in case its null, how can i direct ther user to another page?

Comment: you can use "response.sendRedirect("url_of_another_page"); " when you need to redirect to another page